# Как правильно ограничить поворот gameObject в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть задача, ограничить движение по вертикали пушки от -20 до 20 градусов, если это значение превышается, то поворачивает платформа на которой она стоит, а также необходимо сделать вертикальное поднятие пушки от 0 до 80 градусов.

Я написал код, по отдельности все работает хорошо, но вместе начинается ад.

Мой код:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{

    float fMoveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * fMovementSpeed;
    float fMoveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * fMovementSpeed;

    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * fMoveVertical);
    transform.Translate(Vector3.right * fMoveHorizontal);

    float fRotateHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * Time.deltaTime * fRotateSpeed;
    float fRotateVertical = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * Time.deltaTime * fUpSpeed;

    if (objectCannon.transform.localEulerAngles.z - fRotateHorizontal <= 110.0f &&
        objectCannon.transform.localEulerAngles.z - fRotateHorizontal >= 70.0f)
    {
        objectCannon.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, -fRotateHorizontal);
        Debug.Log("objCannon local: " + objectCannon.transform.localEulerAngles);
        Debug.Log("objCannon global: " + objectCannon.transform.eulerAngles);
    }
    else
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, fRotateHorizontal);


   if(objectCannon.transform.localEulerAngles.x + fRotateVertical + 1  <= 89.0f &&
      objectCannon.transform.localEulerAngles.x + fRotateVertical + 1 >= 9.0f)
    {
        objectCannon.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, -fRotateVertical);
    }

}
```

Comment: Почему в **FixedUpdate** используется **deltaTime**, а не **fixedDeltaTime**?

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский а в целом использование `FixedUpdate` вас не смутило?)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, смутило. Но я устал уже под чередой последних вопросов писать авторам, чего же они все в FixedUpdate лезут.

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский Даже не знал о таком, спасибо. И где лучше это расположить, в LateUpdate?

Comment: Действия с Input необходимо производить в **Update** (т.е. каждый кадр). **LateUpdate** выполняется после вызовов **Update** всех возможных компонентов, поэтому в **LateUpdate** рекомендуют работать с камерой (н-р, позиционирование). **FixedUpdate** же необходим для физических расчетов, и вызывается, как правило, несколько раз за кадр.

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский Физический апдейт вызывается, как правильно, меньше 1 раза на кадр, хотя сейчас все используют 1к1 физические и логические апдейты. Ну уж точно не "несколько раз за кадр".

Answer (score 0):

```
float fRotateHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * Time.deltaTime * fRotateSpeed;
    float fRotateVertical = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * Time.deltaTime * fUpSpeed;

    ///Horizontal
    if (fRotateX + fRotateHorizontal <= 110.0f &&
        fRotateX + fRotateHorizontal >= 70.0f)
    {
        fRotateX += fRotateHorizontal;
    }
    else 
    {
        if (fRotateX > 110.0f) fRotateX = 110.0f;
        if (fRotateX <  70.0f) fRotateX =  70.0f;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x,
                                                                                  transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y + fRotateHorizontal,
                                                                                  transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z), Time.deltaTime * fRotateSpeed);
    }

    //Vertical
    if (fRotateY + fRotateVertical <= 85.0f &&
        fRotateY + fRotateVertical >= 5.0f)
    {
        fRotateY += fRotateVertical;
    }
    objectCannon.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(fRotateY, 0, fRotateX);
```

Comment: It's work good, but not perfectly